# viewWindow property in google charts not working

Tags: google-visualization

I would like to customize values of vertical axis in google chart. In their documentation I've found property for this.It's placed between comments (// ---additionaly added..) in the code, but the graph is not being drawn. Does anyone knows what could be the problem?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/superGear.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png"  href="images/superGear.png">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2013',  1000,      400],
      ['2014',  1170,      460],
      ['2015',  660,       1120],
      ['2016',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},

      // ADDITIONALY ADDED--------------
      vAxis: { 
          viewWindowMode:'explicit',
          viewWindow:{ min:90, max :100 }            
      //---------------------------------
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('lastMonth'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

And div placed into body for displaying the graph

```
<div id="lastMonth" style="height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing `}` for the `vAxis` option:

```
vAxis: { 
    viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
    viewWindow: {
        min:90,
        max: 100
    }
}
```